# ASP .NET MVC , Where is "context" instanced

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is a question about how ASP.NET MVC is working. Now I am trying to understand how the controller pass data from database. And I cannot see where "context" comes from to the args[0] of the constructor in a scaffoled controller.
For example, when you scaffolds a controller from a model called "item", you get ItemsController. The constructor of StaffsConroller goe like;

```
public ItemsController(DbContext context)
{
    _context = context
}
```

The variable "_context" is declared in ItemsController. But where is "context" instanced?

Comment: DbContext is Injected into the constructor via Dependency Injection. See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#dependency-injection-in-the-controller

Answer (score 1):

If you use Entity Framework or configure dependency injection in Startup.cs, then DbContext is created by Dependency Injection. You can research consturctor injection.

> ASP.NET Core applications are configured using dependency injection.
> EF Core can be added to this configuration using AddDbContext in the
> ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
}
```

For more details you can visit these links: [DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core), [Dependency injection in the controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#dependency-injection-in-the-controller)

Comment: Thank you very much. In the visual studio local window , I found the context is add  as a service in the service collection. Can I say that the entity is not eatablished at this timing?

Answer (score 1):

DbContext is Injected into the constructor via Dependency Injection.

When the ItemsController is created (usually every time a new HTTP request arrives at a route mapped to an ItemsController action) the ASP.NET engine knows that ItemsController needs a DbContext and it instantiates a new DbContext there.

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#dependency-injection-in-the-controller